# How can I get the username in the task script?

Tags: camunda, camunda-modeler

I have a task within a workflow that invokes a service on the back end that, along with other data sent from the task, waits for the name of the user who executed that task.

How can I get the user or the username in the task script which is written in Groovy?

Answer (score 0):

You mean a script task following a user task? Assuming you would like to access the name of the user who completed the previous user task from your script, you can store the user name on completion in a process data as shown here:
https://github.com/rob2universe/bpmrun-add-to-dockerimg/blob/e2dd62122b7d006a8a719be96b0a3d043efc9851/configuration/resources/groovyprocess.bpmn#L23

You can then subsequently access the process data in the groovy script task like this:
https://github.com/rob2universe/bpmrun-add-to-dockerimg/blob/e2dd62122b7d006a8a719be96b0a3d043efc9851/configuration/resources/groovyprocess.bpmn#L18

Comment: I have a workflow for making requests and I have a task when canceling this request and I made a system task that would call a service that would modify the status of the request to canceled. I want to send the username that triggered this cancellation to be recorded in the database I have a groovy script that constitutes the payload that will be sent to the service. I want to get the username for inclusion in the payload

Comment: Ok, does my answer not help you do this? You store the username in a process data as shown and then use it in your groovy script as shown. What is missing?

Answer (score 0):

You could either get the task assignee as mentioned by *@rob2universe*, or make use of the `execution` object, which is always accessible from the script (see [Camunda Docs](https://docs.camunda.org/manual/7.17/user-guide/process-engine/scripting/#variables-available-during-script-execution)), as follows:

```
user = execution.getProcessEngineServices().getIdentityService().getCurrentAuthentication().getUserId()
```

See [IdentityService](https://github.com/camunda/camunda-docs-manual/blob/master/content/user-guide/process-engine/identity-service.md).

The username can be then saved to a process variable:

```
execution.setVariable('username', user)
```

And accessed:

```
username = execution.getVariable('username')
```